# How do you convert date format to yyMMdd in cell click event?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, windows-forms-designer

```
var dateString1 = row.Cells["order_date"].Value.ToString();
txt_lot2.Text = row.Cells["lot_no"].Value.ToString() + " - " + dateString1;
```

This is string I am pulling from database on `DataGridView`. Right now it is in `yy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss` format. I want this value to be converted to `yyMMdd` when I click the cell. How do I convert this? Output should be something like:

```
lot_no - order date in yyMMdd
ex of original) K123-19-08-26 12:00:00 AM
ex of to be) K123 - 190826
```

Original database date format is `yy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss` and yes, I only want to convert to `yyMMdd` when I do a *cell click* event to fill up the textBox.

Comment: It looks like "yy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss" initially and you only want to change how it's formatted when someone clicks?

Comment: Dates do not have a format.  They are simply a value.  Formats come in when you convert to string for humans.  If your DGV column type is DateTime (and it should be) you can simply use the format property of the StyleSet to control how it is displayed.  No clicking required.  As it stands, the data does not appear to be a date at all, so you may have to parse it to DateTime in order to format a new string.

Comment: We probably need some clarification, as your expected output confuses the matter.  So you're displaying a DataGrid object, and when a specific cell is clicked, you want *a) The cell to change the display of the DateTime* or... *b) The output to change* - if b, we need clarification on how your output occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DateTime doesn't have a format of its own. You have to specify the format you want when using `ToString()`.

```
var format = "yy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";
var dateFromDB = "19-08-26 08:23:45";
DateTime.TryParseExact(
    dateFromDB, 
    format, 
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
    System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, 
    out DateTime result);
Console.WriteLine(result.ToString("yyMMdd"));
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to convert, just cut 8 chars and remove dashes:

```
var row = row.Cells["order_date"].Value.ToString(); // yy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss format
row = row.Substring(0, 8); // yy-mm-dd format
row = row.Replace("-", ""); // yymmdd format
row.Cells["order_date"] = row;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle three main events:

- `CellBeginEdit`: here you will modify the format of the selected cell
- `CellParsing`: here you will to all data conversion you need
- `CellEndEdit`: here you enable the format back

Here a small working example of the code I've used, please note your code will be more complex because it will need to handle multiple columns and better formatting from the start, consider also I'm using edit mode with F2 to show the modified text:

```
    private void DataGridView1_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e) => 
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Style.Format = "yyMMdd";

    private void DataGridView1_CellParsing(object sender, DataGridViewCellParsingEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime.TryParseExact(dataGridView1.CurrentCell.EditedFormattedValue.ToString(), "yyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime dateToSaveInDb);
        e.Value = dateToSaveInDb;
        e.ParsingApplied = true;
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Style.Format = "yy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";
    }

    private void DataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) => 
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Style.Format = "yy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";
```

I've tested this on a `DataGridView` populated like this

```
        dataGridView1.DataSource = new List<Element> {
            new Element{ EditableDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)},
            new Element{ EditableDate = DateTime.Now},
            new Element{ EditableDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)}
        }; ;
        dataGridView1.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnF2;
```

Here the example class used

```
    public class Element { public DateTime EditableDate { get; set; } }
```